# Joomla "pretty urls" with nginx allow index.php/pretty/url as well as index.phppretty/url (notice the absence of slash)

Tags: nginx, rewrite, php-fpm, joomla

I am trying to install my first LEMP stack and, after a lot of hours and reading, it's working pretty well (Damn, the www-data group write permissions issue was a tough one).

Anyway, my Joomla site is now working and performing better than ever, but I have noticed a strange issue with the pretty urls:

If I access to `www.mysite.com/index.php/some/content/alias/` everything is good. However, it's also OK if I access `www.mysite.com/index.phpsome/content/alias/` (notice the absence of the slash after `index.php`).

Is that the expected behavior? I know end users won't access those anyway, but its mere existence is driving me nuts, because it should throw a 404, right?

This is my config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.bla;
    return       301 http://www.domain.bla$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name www.domain.bla;

    root /home/domain/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.html;

    #Specify a charset
    charset utf-8;

    # Custom 404 page
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    # Include the basic h5bp config set
    # The error remains if I comment this out, so that's not the problem
    include h5bp/basic.conf;

    # Enable PHP-FPM
    include fastcgi_php.conf;
}
```

fastcgi_php.conf:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /var/www/html;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    # fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

... and fastcgi_params:

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS           $https if_not_empty;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
```

By the way, `cgi.fix_pathinfo` is set to 0.

Any clue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Both URLs hit your final `try_files` clause: `/index.php?q=$request_uri`

As the file does not exist and the only location block that matches is "/". The regex location block does not match initially, as it does not end with ".php", that is until rewritten by the `try_files` directive mentioned above.

Also, your `fastcgi_split_path_info` directive does not really do anything, as URLs with path info cannot match that location block.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll give it a shot and try to come up with a solution. Thanks!